# How can I check if Google Map co-ordinates lie in London Congestion Zone?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web-applications

I am trying to check if google map co-ordinates lie in London Congestion Zone. How can I detect if the co-ordinates lie inside the boundary of London Congestion Zone or Is there any other way around.

Comment: You need create polygon for London Congestion Zone and after that use method [containsLocation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly.containsLocation) of Google Maps JavaScript API geometry library.

Comment: https://blog.mapbox.com/geofencing-for-londons-congestion-charge-zone-8949c777bb4e

Comment: I really don’t understand why this question got vote down so much

Comment: @DavidBradshaw yeah I also don't understand why so much down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The congestion charge area is available in GeoJSON format from this site.

https://data.cdrc.ac.uk/dataset/ccz

You can import this data into Google Maps using `map.data.loadGeoJson`. Some example code can be found at:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple

You can then use `map.geometry.poly.containsLocation` from the map API to answer your question